# TYPO3 content element icon (fluid)

Tags: typo3, backend, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I can not figure out how to display icons of content elements in the backend page view. I modified some content elements of the extension ws_t3bootstrap and expected the icons would stay the same... I cleared all caches however the icon stays transparent...
[image]

Typo3 7.6.10, flux-developer 7.4.0, fluid 7.6.0

Comment: Did you modify existing element or create a copy and then modify or create a copy to your custom extension?

Comment: I made minor modifications in existing element and i did not change the filename (stays: example.html). I did not change <flux:form id="example" options="{group: 'Bootstrap', icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'Icons/bootstrap.png\')}'}"> either.